# adding basic authentication to Solr 8.6.1

Tags: authentication, solr

We are having some difficulty when adding basic authentication to Solr 8.6.1. We are following [this document](https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_1/basic-authentication-plugin.html), and we have created `security.json` file, which is successful (since Solr instance will ask userId and password when it starts.) Our difficulty happens when trying to enable the global authentication settings: we did pass the `-Dsolr.httpclient.builder.factory=org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.PreemptiveBasicAuthClientBuilderFactory` system property,and we also set the `-Dbasicauth=username:password` property as follows:

```
// the following is the last time of our Solr Dockerfile:
CMD ["solr-foreground", "-Dsolr.httpclient.builder.factory=org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.PreemptiveBasicAuthClientBuilderFactory", "-Dbasicauth=username:secret"]
```

However, the calls to retrieve data from Solr all come back with `Error 401 require authentication`.

Could someone please kindly let us know what did we miss?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following; why are you configuring the authentication for the client in your solr-foreground call? Which calls are you making that fails with a 401? How did you add authentication to those calls?

Comment: @MatsLindh: we are making a call like this: SolrClient solr = new HttpSolrClient.Builder(CollectionUtil.getCollectionPath(CollectionUtil.Collection.OPERATION_MODE)).build(); and then we do solr.query(...). and this is where it gives us 401. We have lots of calls like this, and we don't want to add username/password to each one of them, that is why we configured the authentication in the foreground call, and we did that by following the Solr documents. Hope this gives you enough information?

Comment: But the `solr-foreground` call _is on the server_ in the Dockerfile? Why would that affect the client code you're writing for querying the server? If that would do what you want it to do, that would just be the same as disabling authentication, right?

Comment: totally agree, and we have the same question! but what we did is based on our understanding of the document... did we miss anything? which part should we change?

Comment: You should do for the JVM _that runs your client code_ - it's not about a server related change. There shouldn't be any need to make this change to your Solr server from what you've explained.

Comment: ah! let me try that. thank you!

Comment: yes, that was it - adding the configurations on the JVM that runs the client code, and then it works nicely. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to set the correct options on *the client* - not on the server. This is a setting that affects how the client that connects to Solr authenticates.

So when running your application, give the parameter to the `java` command (or configure it to be the default parameter through ant/maven/gradle/etc.

Setting it on the docker container will not do anything useful.